# Citation with two years

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

Let's say I'm citing Author (1995/2010), where the latter year is a recent edition (the one consulted), but the actual year of publication is 1995. Adding `1995/2010` won't do it.

I use `natbib`, and I can't seem to find a solution here... Does anyone know how to do it?